# How to set size of items inside of UIStackView

Tags: swift, uistackview

How can I set size of items inside of `UIStackview`. Not all items will have the same size. I tried setting the distribution to fill but that does nothing. Thank you in advance.

This is my current stack

```
lazy var POIInfoStack:UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

Comment: You need to set constraint sizes for the items in the UIStackview and that ideally would solve your issue. I recommend doing so in storyboard than in code if you're new to UIStackViews

Comment: @DrPatience really help a lot thanks if you want to add that as your answer so i can accept it

Comment: You're welcome, that's added now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set constraint sizes for the items in the UIStackview and that ideally would solve your issue. I recommend doing so in storyboard than in code if you're new to UIStackViews